# Why nginx returns 301 status code when trying to open a directory?

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration

I am trying to understand how Nginx works. Now I'm working on `index` and `try_files` directives. My config file is this:

```
events {}
http {
  rewrite_log on;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log debug;

  server {
    root /app;
    listen 8080;
    index index.html;
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
  }
}
```

Also `/app/` tree directory is:

```
/app
|-- abcd.html
|-- file.php
|-- index.html
|-- index.php
|-- sss
|   `-- index.html
|-- style.css
`-- thumb.png
```

When I try to open `localhost:8080` everything works as expected. It first uses `location /` context. Then uses `$uri/` to read the root directory. Then because index file name has been specified, it uses index file in that directory. Also, the log file can show that:

```
...
2021/10/27 11:37:49 [debug] 1297#1297: *1 test location: "/"
2021/10/27 11:37:49 [debug] 1297#1297: *1 using configuration "/"
...
2021/10/27 11:37:49 [debug] 1297#1297: *1 generic phase: 12
2021/10/27 11:37:49 [debug] 1297#1297: *1 try files handler
2021/10/27 11:37:49 [debug] 1297#1297: *1 http script var: "/"
2021/10/27 11:37:49 [debug] 1297#1297: *1 trying to use file: "/" "/app/"
2021/10/27 11:37:49 [debug] 1297#1297: *1 http script var: "/"
2021/10/27 11:37:49 [debug] 1297#1297: *1 trying to use dir: "/" "/app/"
2021/10/27 11:37:49 [debug] 1297#1297: *1 try file uri: "/"
2021/10/27 11:37:49 [debug] 1297#1297: *1 generic phase: 13
2021/10/27 11:37:49 [debug] 1297#1297: *1 content phase: 14
2021/10/27 11:37:49 [debug] 1297#1297: *1 open index "/app/index.html"
2021/10/27 11:37:49 [debug] 1297#1297: *1 internal redirect: "/index.html?"
...
```

But when I open `localhost:8080/sss`, It first responds with a redirection to `localhost:8080/sss/`, then opens the index file inside the `sss/` directory. Here is the logs:

```
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 test location: "/"
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 using configuration "/"
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 rewrite phase: 3
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 post rewrite phase: 4
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 generic phase: 5
...
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 try files handler
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 http script var: "/sss"
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 trying to use file: "/sss" "/app/sss"
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 http script var: "/sss"
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 trying to use dir: "/sss" "/app/sss"
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 try file uri: "/sss"
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 generic phase: 13
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 content phase: 14
...
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 content phase: 18
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 http filename: "/app/sss"
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 add cleanup: 000055AA4A146290
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 http static fd: -1
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 http dir
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 http finalize request: 301, "/sss?" a:1, c:1
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 http special response: 301, "/sss?"
2021/10/27 11:46:07 [debug] 1297#1297: *3 http set discard body
...
```

Why it didn't respond with the index file inside the `sss/` directory, just like the root directory, without external redirection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$uri/` term on a `try_files` statement works the same way as Nginx default behaviour.

If you provide a URI **without** a trailing `/` that points to a directory, Nginx will first append a trailing `/` using an external redirect (i.e. `301`).

If you provide a URI **with** a trailing `/` that points to a directory, the `index` directive will be invoked and may generate an internal redirect to whichever file is specified (e.g. `index.html`).

Although [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) is clear that a trailing `/` is required by the `index` directive. I cannot find where the former behaviour is documented.

Comment: So why is not the first request responded to with external redirection, even though it doesn't have trailing `/`? i.e `localhost:8080`. Also in location context, I have specified to try a file with added trailing `/`.

Comment: It does have a trailing `/`. Your browser's address bar is hiding it from you, but the server receives the URI as `GET /` - see your access log.